# Como alianiear elementos en una tabla repartidos sobre diferentes celulas de una fila?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una tabla en la qual meto datos de mi base de datos. El valor en verde es resultado del valor en rojo, aunque la cantidad de valores en rojo varia. Para que el usuario a primera vista sepa ubicarse, quiero aliniar los diferentes tipos de datos de una misma fila.

El resultado que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi plan era meter cada tipo de dato en un div tag con la misma classe. Pero cual es el comando css para alinear todos los div de la misma classe.

```css
.test1{
 display: inline-block;
 
}
```

```html
<table class="tg" border="1">

  <tr>   
    <td class="tg-yw4l"> <div class="test2">ValorTypo1<br />ValorTypo1<br />ValorTypo1</div>  <div class="test1">ValorTypo2</div>     </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"> <div class="test2"></div>             <div class="test1">ValorTypo2</div>     </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"> <div class="test2">ValorTypo1<br />ValorTypo1</div>      <div class="test1">ValorTypo2</div>    </td> 
    <td class="tg-yw4l"> <div class="test2">ValorTypo1<br />ValorTypo1</div>      <div class="test1">ValorTypo2</div>     </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi consejo es que hagas algo una fila para cada apartado. En realidad es lo que pides, es para lo que existen las filas de una tabla.

Puedes personalizar el estilo de la tabla a tu gusto después.

La segunda opción es utilizar `div` y prescindir de la tabla.

```css
.primertr{
color:green;
}
.segundotr{
color:red;
}
tr{
vertical-align:top;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
Ejemplo tabla
<table class="tg" border="1">

  <tr class="primertr">   
    <td> 
    <div>ValorTypo1<br />ValorTypo1<br />ValorTypo1</div>  
   </td>
    
    <td> 
    <div></div>             
    </td>
    
    <td> 
    <div>ValorTypo1<br />ValorTypo1</div>
    </td> 
    
    <td> 
    <div>ValorTypo1<br />ValorTypo1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="segundotr">   
    <td> 

    <div>ValorTypo2</div>     
    <div>ValorTypo2</div>     
    </td>
    
    <td>         
    <div>ValorTypo2</div>
    </td>
    
    <td> 
  <div>ValorTypo2</div>
    </td> 
    
    <td> 
  <div>ValorTypo2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

Ejemplo div
<div class="row primertr">
  <div class="block">ValorTypo1<br>ValorTypo1</div>
  <div class="block">ValorTypo1</div>
  <div class="block">ValorTypo1</div>
</div>
<div class="row segundotr">
  <div class="block">ValorTypo2</div>
  <div class="block">ValorTypo2<br>ValorTypo2</div>
  <div class="block">ValorTypo2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me gustaria hacerlo a traves de css.

Comment: Ya estás realizando los estilos necesarios con css. Puedes darle el formato que quieras con las propiedades `border` por ejemplo. Pero eso no quita que tengas que añadir una fila más en el código html.

Comment: es mas como la respuesta de este chico http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/wZB9z/ en este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277311/horizontally-aligning-divs

Comment: Pero en ese caso sólo utiliza una fila. No puedes aplicar dos tipos de alineación a un sólo elemento. Cada elemento tiene su propiedad. Tu ya estás utilizando tablas, lo que hace que ya los tengas alineados horizontalmente.

Comment: No estás utilizando `div` sobre un `body`. Los tienes dentro de una tabla, que ya tiene su propia estructura con filas y columnas. Es por ello que necesitas una fila para cada caso.

Comment: digamos que la tabla impide cualquier intento de reestructurar el contenido, es eso lo que me intentas decir?

Comment: Del modo que tu pides si. Estás intentando alinear unos `divs` que ya están alineados bajo la etiqueta `tr`.

Comment: entientiendo. entonces solo me queda cambiar la estructura de la tabla entera.

Comment: Mira te he editado la respuesta haciendolo con los `div` como indicas. En ese caso ya no tiene sentido tener una tabla.

Comment: muy bien gracias por las sugerencias.

Answer (score 0):

Aprobecha los `td`s de la tabla en lugar de meterle tantos divs. He intentado darle el estilo mas parecido al de tu captura.

```css
table{
  border: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td{
  border: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.test2{
  color:red;
}

.test1{
  color:green;
    padding-top:10px;
}

table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg" border="1">

  <tr>   
    <td class="test2"> 
      ValorTypo1
    </td>
    <td class="test2"> 
      ValorTypo1
    </td>
    <td class="test2"> 
       
    </td>
    <td class="test2"> 
       ValorTypo1
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td class="test2"> 
      ValorTypo1
    </td>
    <td class="test2"> 
       
    </td>
    <td class="test2"> 
        
    </td>
    <td class="test2"> 
      ValorTypo1
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td class="test2"> 
       
    </td>
    <td class="test2"> 
       
    </td>
    <td class="test2"> 
       
    </td>
    <td class="test2"> 
      ValorTypo1
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td class="test1"> 
      ValorTypo2
    </td> 
    <td class="test1"> 
      ValorTypo2
    </td> 
    <td class="test1"> 
      ValorTypo2
    </td> 
    <td class="test1"> 
      ValorTypo2
    </td> 
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Debe haber otra manera. Lo que haces tu es anyadir mas td y tr y cambias la estructura completa.

Comment: Es lo que comenta en la otra respuesta, si lo quieres dentro de una tabla esta seria la estructura correcta. Si lo quieres en divs no uses la tabla.